# Why is the axis shown differently from my raw data?

Tags: powerbi

I am modelling raw data using Stacked Column Chart by Power BI.

Expected Data:

```
201811
201812
201901 until
201910
```

[[image]]

Actual Result shown on axis:

```
201800
201820
201840
```

[[image]]

Comment: Please add the image in the post instead of providing it as a link.

Comment: @vikashsingh The OP can't do this, because his reputation is only 1.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the axis type - is it Continuous or Categorical:

[image]

The top image is continuous, while in the bottom one axis type is set to categorical:

[image]

For Continuous axis type, the value bar is shown at the exact position between minimum and maximum values. It is used for numeric values. For Categorical, each value bars are displayed next to each other with labels showing the exact value. This is normally used for text values (e.g. month or weekday names).